# Showing that this vector space is infinite dimensional

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

Let $$V:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{(x_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}:x_i\in\mathbb{C},\space{}x_i=0\space{}\forall{}\space{}i>n\right\}.$$

I am trying to show that $V$ is infinite dimensional and that its Hamel basis is $(e_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$.

I tried showing this by contradiction but didn't manage to:

I defined $V_n:=\{(x_1,...,x_n,0,...)|x_i\in\mathbb{C}\}$ which has a basis $E_n=\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ and  its clear that $V_n\subset{}V_{n+1}$ hence $E_n$ spans all $V_i$ for all $i=1,...,n$.

But am not sure where to go with this.

Also a side question:

I understand that a Hamel basis can be infinite, but only considers finite sums. What is meant by simply a 'basis' in texts, does this then include infinite sums (is this referred to a schauder basis)?

any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Any finite set of vectors is contained in some $V_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $v_1, ... ,v_n \in V.$. For each $i$ with $1 \le i \le n$ let $i_*$ be such that $v_i(j)=0  \text { if } j \ge i_*$, Let $$M=\max\{i_*, 1 \le i \le n \}.$$ Define $v$ by $$v(M+1)=1, v(i)=0  \text { for } i \ne M+1.$$ Then $$v \notin\text  {span}(v_1, ... ,v_n)$$ so no finite set can span $V.$ On the other hand, if $v \in V$ then there exists $K$ such that $v(i)=0 \text { for } i >K$ so $v \in \text {span}(e_1, ... ,e_K) \subseteq \text {span}(e_1,...).$ Since no non-trivial finite linear combination of $e_1,...$ can be 0, the set $\{e_1, ...  \}$ is a Hamel basis of $V.$